# What is an adequate test for (null)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

In my code I am using this test to check that the user has selected something in a pickerView:

```
if ( !selection || [selection isEqualToString:@"Select..."] ) {}
```

However, many posts on Stack Overflow recommend either using `NSNull` or a test like this example below:

```
if ( selection.length == 0 || [selection isEqualToString:@"(null)"] ) {}
```

There are also a number of variations of the above line of code all testing for a null where I am just using: `!selection`

Is my test incomplete and open to bugs creeping in?
What is the difference between the `!selection` and these other tests?

Comment: Could it be that you are mixing up OR (`||`) and AND (`&&`). Anyways, I would recommend using AND as that would skip the conditional already if the first expression results to `NO` (aka FALSE). So my bet goes to `if (selection && [selection isEqualToString:@"foo"])`. But then again, any method on a nil pointer will return `NO`/`nil`/`0`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but perhaps I was not clear enough - my code is working it successfully tests for a null (i.e. the user did not spin the pickerView and therefore nothing is selected) OR they did spin the pickerView but ended up selecting my dummy value which politely asks the user to "Select... My question is more specific to the testing for null conditions which seems to be more explicit in other posts here on stack overflow making me feel inadequate. So I am asking if I am doing enough in my test...

Comment: It's hard to answer whether you need to check for `NSNull` without knowing what `selection` really is. How is it set? It seems unlikely that it's going to be `NSNull` (and if it were, `isEqualToString:@"(null)"` wouldn't be how you'd test for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only bug I can foresee is a localization bug. What if you are setting the picker data somewhere using `NSLocalizedString()`, and forgot to properly check the `@"Select..."` according to the current localization? That would be very annoying, especially if your testers don't thoroughly test all localizations...

However, `!selection` and `selection.length == 0` should both be OK, even though selection would be `nil`, and `nil.length` won't make sense... So, I'd say go with:

```
if ( !selection || [selection isEqualToString:@"(null)"] ) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
selection.length == 0
```

is good if you want to treat a zero length string and a nil as the same thing, which is often the case. Because its safe to send a message to a nil object and the result will be nil, 0 or 0.0 you can do this safely.

You only need to use isEqualToString: to you have other possible string you want to treat as the equivalent to nil, for example @"(null)", I see this can happen when convert text data in  some kind of Object graph, I sometimes see this in JSON where the code generating the JSON doesn't handle null correctly.

NSNull is a object and you may have to test for that as well if you may get an instance of NSNull in place of nil, this happens with a lot of JSON parsers. Its also a way to store nil in collection objects (NSArray and NSDictionarys)

Comment: You'll get @"(null) using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nil]`, for me that would be an indicator of a bad framework which i'd prefer not to use.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand the difference between nil, NSNull and NULL.

`nil` - (id)0, represents the `id` objects that are not initialized but due to the logic it can not be used in some patterns like you can not add nil value to the array.

`NSNull` - a singleton class, used for the initialized `nil` representation - you can add it to the arrays.

`NULL` - (void*)0, represents any uninitialized object, it must be there for backwards `C` support

For the initialization check i'm usually using the macros `(obj != nil) && (obj != (id)[NSNull null])`

And for the empty string check you can use

```
((obj != nil) && (obj != (id)[NSNull null]) && obj.length > 0 && [obj containsOnlyWhitespaceOrNewline] == NO)
```

Comment: While your at it there is also `Nil`.

Comment: Right, used for classes though.

Comment: Check your brackets on the last line.

Comment: The first two cases are automagically handled by the third case, since if you send a message to nil or null, it is going to come back as 0 (or NO) anyway....  You can save a lot of typing by just skipping those.  :)

Comment: @lnafziger of course i will not save any typing because that will be at helper function :) thank you for the note.

Comment: Okay, while it may be a helper, it is still code that doesn't do anything but use up extra CPU cycles for no good reason.  :)

Comment: @lnafziger i'm not so sure, can you share the benchmarks of comparing addresses and sending the message ?

Comment: Well, you are doing both....  I guess it would depend on your mix of nil/non-nil values.

Comment: @lnafziger right you are, i'll keep the method as it is though, it does no harm i think

Comment: For what it's worth, you have to have somewhere in the range of 90-95% nil's in order for your method to be faster (I just benchmarked it over 100,000,000 trials both ways several times and with 15% nil's, it was a 2.5 second difference.)  Granted, for "normal" use, it won't make a big difference, but you did get me curious so I had to check.  :)

Comment: Thats surprisingly high, i'll have to optimize the method then, thank you for pushing me to the bright side :)